# WooCommerce: Show Active Coupon Price on Single Product Page

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

While I love how the discount for a coupon is applied in the cart and checkout of Woocommerce, I think it would be cool to have the discounted price shown on the actual product page.

So, if a coupon code has been applied at 30% off, it would be cool to show the price greyed out (or slashed), with a discounted price shown for the coupon. I have both single and variable products.

I've seen functions for the cart page, but that's already built in for the most part, but not the actual product pages.

Is this possible?